# Aligning text view below text view in card view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-cardview

I just implemented card view in my app, and want to put 2 different texts in it (one is 18dp, second is 9dp) in white space bellow image.
Also I want to put arrow image to the right side of card view. But I'm getting problem there. If I use 2 different Textviews I can't allign the other one below the first one. And if I use only one Text view, I can't make the text have 2 different sizes.

Here's what I'm talking about:

[image]

As you can see, this is only one Text view wroten as `Text1\nText2`
I can't put  size of 18dp to Text 1 and 9dp to Text 2.

Any solution to this??

Here's the XML code:

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:id="@+id/Vjezbe"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
            android:onClick="Vjezbe">
         <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="130dp"
                android:id="@+id/imageView6"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:layout_column="0" />

             <TableRow
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="match_parent">

                 <TextView
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                     android:text="Text 1\nText 2"
                     android:id="@+id/textView25"
                     android:textSize="18dp"
                     android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                     android:layout_weight="0.9" />

                 <ImageView
                     android:layout_width="40dp"
                     android:layout_height="40dp"
                     android:id="@+id/imageView17"
                     android:background="@mipmap/strelica"
                     android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
                     android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                     android:layout_marginBottom="1dp" />
             </TableRow>


         </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: use linear layout with orientation as vertical and add two text view

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of using one `TextView` Use `LinearLayout` with orientation as vertical and add two text view

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"     
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" 
    android:layout_weight="0.9" >

    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/textView25" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" 
        android:text="Text 1" 
        android:textSize="18dp" /> 

    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" 
        android:text="Text 2" 
        android:textSize="18dp" /> 
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Code example would be great

Comment: But i want use only card view rather than Linerlayout
Please help

Comment: You can use  cardview as parent layout easy!